# How do I configure RubyMine 5 to edit remote files over SSH

Tags: ruby, ssh, virtualbox, remote-debugging, rubymine

I've got sort of a simple problem, but I can't seem to find any conclusive answers on the web. So, I have Ubuntu Server running in VirtualBox with Ruby and Rails installed.

What I want to do, is edit the files in the VM over SSH using RubyMine 5.0 on the Windows host machine (just like I can in Eclipse).

The problem is I can't find how to do that. I'm pretty sure it can be done, because I've found some related articles on the web, but none of them show me how I can configure RubyMine to do that.

I've searched every option in the menu and I can't figure it out by myself, so a "to the point" explanation would really be of help.

Thanks

Comment: You can't do it without syncing remote project to the local disk, see http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-1398.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that the feature is missing in RubyMine. If that's true, it would be too bad. I'd have to go back to Eclipse.

Comment: Ok, so I've poked around PHP Storm 7 (also a JetBrains project) for a bit. It seems that you can now configure it to work on a remote project over SFTP. Trouble is, the Upload on Save option isn't ticked by default. Also, it only uploads files automatically; if some changes occur on the server, they are NOT downloaded automatically. And now for the worst part: for some reason, this option IS NOT available in RubyMine 5 or 6.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to do this natively in RubyMine. My solution is to mount the remote filesystem to a local folder using sshfs.

- Linux you can get sshfs through your package manager.
- OSX you can get it [here](http://osxfuse.github.io/) make sure to install both OSX fuse and SSHFS. The version on [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh/) did not work for me on OSX 10.9.4 so I recommend using the packages from the link.
- Windows you can use win-sshfs, I've had good results using [Chocolaty](https://chocolatey.org/) to install [win-sshfs](https://chocolatey.org/packages/win-sshfs)

To use on Linux/OSX:

- Open your terminal.
- `mkdir MountFolder`
- `sshfs user@server.com:/path/to/project MountFolder/`

To use on Windows:

- Use the GUI.

After you've mounted the remote file system open RubyMine and select Open Directory and browse to the project.

This is the best solution I can come up with until JetBrains supports it natively.